# Laravel Backpack Filters doesnt do anything after click

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

Im new to Laravel Packpack. My issue is I have filters using this code

```
$this->crud->addFilter(
            ['name' => 'created_at', 'type' => 'date_range', 'label' => 'Bid Date'],
            false,
            function ($value) {
                $dates = json_decode($value);
                $this->crud->addClause('where', 'created_at', '>=', $dates->from);
                $this->crud->addClause('where', 'created_at', '<=', $dates->to . ' 23:59:59');
            });
        $this->crud->addFilter(
            ['name' => 'name', 'type' => 'text', 'label' => 'Name'],
            false, 
            function ($value) {
                $this->crud->addClause('where', 'name', 'LIKE', "%$value%");
            });
        $this->crud->addFilter(
            ['name' => 'email', 'type' => 'text', 'label' => 'Email'],
            false, 
            function ($value) {
                $this->crud->addClause('where', 'email', 'LIKE', "%$value%");
            });
```

It shows the filter like the image below but if Im trying to click it, it doesnt do anything.

[image]

Can you share anything to me to fix this? Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done my solution was the cdn of bootstrap.min.js and popper.js is broken :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example modification for debugging purposes:

```
  $this->crud->addFilter(
    ['name' => 'created_at', 'type' => 'date_range', 'label' => 'Bid Date'],
    false,
    function ($value) {
        $dates = json_decode($value);
        $this->crud->addClause('where', 'created_at', '>=', $dates->from);
        $this->crud->addClause('where', 'created_at', '<=', $dates->to . ' 23:59:59');
    }
);

$this->crud->addFilter(
    ['name' => 'name', 'type' => 'text', 'label' => 'Name'],
    false, 
    function ($value) {
        $this->crud->addClause('where', 'name', 'LIKE', "%$value%");
    }
);

$this->crud->addFilter(
    ['name' => 'email', 'type' => 'text', 'label' => 'Email'],
    false, 
    function ($value) {
        $this->crud->addClause('where', 'email', 'LIKE', "%$value%");
    }
);
```

Please check that.